# Extending Hallojs in Django Wagtail With Edit Source Button

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I've been abel to add an an 'Edit Html' source button to my editor with the following hook:

```
@hooks.register('insert_editor_js')
def enable_source():
    return format_html(
        """
        <script>
            registerHalloPlugin('hallohtml');
        </script>
        """
    )
```

It adds a button, but I can't figure out how to add an icon - see screenshot below with no icon.

[image]

All buttons except no icon make the source editor work great.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to edit rich text fields at the raw HTML level, there's almost certainly something you should be doing better in your data model - rich text fields are only intended for simple text formatting. If you're trying to do layouts / fonts etc, that's the job of the template designer; if you're trying to embed tables / diagrams etc, look at StreamField (https://torchbox.com/blog/rich-text-fields-and-faster-horses/, http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/topics/streamfield.html).

Comment: Thanks.. I am already using Streamfield, but overlooked that it didn't add any pre-defined styles, so placing my custom content in fit nicely onto the page.  If you place you comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks again - loving Wagtail!!

Comment: With the plugin Studio Rooster will be able to insert non-breaking spaces, subscripts and superscripts, anchors with the target attribute (if he adds `'a': attribute_rule({'href': check_url, 'target': True})` to the `whitelist_element_rules`), emdashes, etc. None of that is a matter of layouts, templates, tables or diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [insert_editor_css](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) hook to provide additional CSS files to the editor.

```
@hooks.register('insert_editor_css')
def editor_css():
    return format_html(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{}">',
        static('demo/css/editor-overrides.css')
    )
```

In your hallohtml plugin JS, assign `icon-hallohtml` to the button and use the following CSS to style it with an H character:

```
.hallotoolbar .halloformat .ui-button-text .icon-hallohtml:before {
    content:'H';
}
```