# Custom button for editor?

Tags: wagtail

I have add html code view to the editor but can't work out how to add an icon to the button.

myapp/wagtail_hooks.py:

```
...
@hooks.register('insert_editor_js')
def editor_js():
    js_files = [
    ]
    js_includes = format_html_join('\n', '',
    ((settings.STATIC_URL, filename) for filename in js_files)
    )

    return js_includes + format_html(
        """
        <script>
          registerHalloPlugin('hallohtml');
        </script>
        """
```

It all works fine but the button is blank.

If I inspect the element in firefox I can see that the button is set as null_button.

```
<button id="1fb89f85-cd4f-3da5-3d97-063187f940b6-Edit HTML" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only null_button" title="Edit HTML">          <span class="ui-button-text">            <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>          </span>        </button>
```

What file do I need to add the icon info to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Hallojs in Djang Wagtail With Edit Source Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250432/extending-hallojs-in-djang-wagtail-with-edit-source-button)

Comment: The answer in that post states "use the following CSS to style it with an H character:" but I don't know where to add that code.

Comment: You should put it in the file you specified in the insert_editor_css hook - demo/css/editor-overrides.css, in the example code. (If you're not familiar with the details of where Django looks for static files, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/ )